# Express-Validator not performing check

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-validator

I am developing a simple program using Express. I have added Express-Validator to carry out checks on an EJS index file

Declaration:

`const {check, validationResult} = require('express-validator/check');`

Usage:

```
//This is to post the added customer
app.post('/users/add',
check('first_name').isLength({min:5}).withMessage('Name min 5 char'), (req, res) => {

});
```

Test:
I am entering a 3 character name in the name field, but this is not being caught.

Answer (score 0):

As of v5.3.1 (latest version), express-validator doesn't automatically respond to the request for you.

The `check()` function runs the checks you configure on the fields that match, and stores the errors in the request.
Then, you have to use `validationResult()` in order to find out if any of your validations failed, like this:

```
app.post('/users/add', [
  check('first_name').isLength({ min: 5 }).withMessage('Name min 5 char')
], (req, res) => {
  // Finds the validation errors in this request and wraps them in an object with handy functions
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }

  // Proceed and create the user
});
```

More available in [the Getting Started guide](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/index.html) and the [Validation Result API](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-result-api.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. Very helpful

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) If my answer helped you, please upvote it and mark it as the correct one.